# Como añadir unas segunda modal box

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal

estaba buscando la manera de hacer una galería de imágenes con thumbnails y vista en grande. En [w3schools encontré justo lo que quería](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp), pero solo me funciona con una imagen, que es para lo que esta preparado en el ejemplo. No entiendo mucho de programación aun y es por eso que a pesar de haber probado de todo no consigo hacer que el script junto con el modal funcione para una segunda foto y sucesivamente. Podría alguien echarme una mano. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con este ejemplo, teniendo un `div` que contiene las imágenes, sólo tienes que iterar sobre sus nodos hijos (que son las imágenes) y aplicarles el método que tienes.

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Probando</title>
    <style>
        #myImg {
            border-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }

        #myImg:hover {
            opacity: 0.7;
        }

        /* The Modal (background) */
        .modal {
            display: none;
            /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed;
            /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1;
            /* Sit on top */
            padding-top: 100px;
            /* Location of the box */
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            /* Full width */
            height: 100%;
            /* Full height */
            overflow: auto;
            /* Enable scroll if needed */
            background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
            /* Black w/ opacity */
        }

        /* Modal Content (Image) */
        .modal-content {
            margin: auto;
            display: block;
            width: 80%;
            max-width: 700px;
        }

        /* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
        #caption {
            margin: auto;
            display: block;
            width: 80%;
            max-width: 700px;
            text-align: center;
            color: #ccc;
            padding: 10px 0;
            height: 150px;
        }

        /* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
        .modal-content,
        #caption {
            animation-name: zoom;
            animation-duration: 0.6s;
        }

        @keyframes zoom {
            from {
                transform: scale(0)
            }

            to {
                transform: scale(1)
            }
        }

        /* The Close Button */
        .close {
            position: absolute;
            top: 15px;
            right: 35px;
            color: #f1f1f1;
            font-size: 40px;
            font-weight: bold;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }

        .close:hover,
        .close:focus {
            color: #bbb;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        /* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
        @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
            .modal-content {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<div id="imagenes">
    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/5.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/6.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/7.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/8.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/9.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/10.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/11.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/12.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/13.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/14.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/15.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/16.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/17.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/18.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/19.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/20.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- The Close Button -->
    <span class="close">&times;</span>

    <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
    <img class="modal-content" id="img01">

    <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
    <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
<script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    var imagenes = document.getElementById("imagenes").childNodes;
    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
    imagenes.forEach(function (img) {
        var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
        var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
        img.onclick = function () {
            modal.style.display = "block";
            modalImg.src = this.src;
            captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
        }
    });

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

</script>

</html>
```

Hay otras variantes, por ejemplo: asignarle una misma clase a cada imagen y aplicar un procedimiento similar al anterior, etc.